# valence download topic file

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I can successfully access topic by calling
   GET (orgUnitId)/content/topics/(topicId)
which returns a file-topic (TOPIC_T=1).

But when I try to access the file itself
   GET (orgUnitId)/content/topics/(topicId)/file
I'm receiving 404.

Files are there and can be independently accessible thru URL and/or UI.

Comment: Can you please add to your question what version of LMS you're making this call against? (Note that the route to retrieve a file directly from the course content space was only recently added with LE v10.2.0.)

Comment: Any other way to get content?

Answer (score 0):

Prior to LE 10.2.0, the `Url` property associated with the topic when appended to the LMS domain should be able to fetch the raw file; however, this will probably require your calling web container to have an active user session with the right permissions to see that course content. If the calling web container doesn't have an active session, the container should redirect to the LMS' log-in path, but I don't believe that deep-linking is supported right down to the content topic level (that is, after the log-in the auth process may not support redirecting back to the URL to fetch the content).

With LE 10.2.0, the Valence Learning Framework API provides a route to fetch a file topic's file content directly, by file ID, without having to use the `Url` property.